# Jquery/Javascript onchange.replace() function killing me

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

**Hello & Thank you for looking**

I have an editable Jquery table that automatically creates a new row when tabbed out of the last line. The script duplicates the previous row, but changes the row number in the name and id fields.

*newName* works and updates great;

*newId* works and updates great;

I am trying the same thing in an **onchange** attribute of one duplicated Select Box:

**Hoping to Change from:**

```
    <select name="det[5][item]" onchange="getitemprice(this.value,5);">
```

**To:**

```
    <select name="det[6][item]" onchange="getitemprice(this.value,6);">
```

but Javascript keeps breaking when I add the line:

```
    newOne      = elem.onchange.replace(/[0-9]+/i, config.formPos );
```

into the addRow() funcion below!

```
    function addRow() {
        var tr = $(table).find('tr:not(.noedit):first').clone();
        //console.dir(tr);
        addFormPos();
        if($(tr).find("input, select, textarea").length > 0) {
            $(tr).find("input, textarea, select").each(function(index, elem) {
                // Change the name of the fields
                var newName = '';
                var newId = '';
                var newOne = '';
                if(config.formPos !== '') {
                    newName     = elem.name.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/i, '[' + config.formPos + ']');
                    newId       = elem.id.replace(/[0-9]+/i, config.formPos );
                    newOne      = elem.onchange.replace(/[0-9]+/i, config.formPos );
                }else {
                    newName = elem.name;
                }

                if(elem.type == 'checkbox' || elem.type == 'radio') {
                     $(elem).attr({'name': newName, 'checked': false})
                }else {
                     $(elem).attr({'name': newName, 'id': newId, 'onchange': newOne});
                }
                $(elem)
            });
            $(tr).find("input:radio, input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
        }
```

What am i missing? how can I make it as easy as the newId and newName elements? 
Thank you all for your help with what I'm sure you will see as absurdly easy.

**-Nic-**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inlined event handler use jQuery handler like

```
<select name="det[6][item]" class="myselect" data-formpos="5">
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(document).on('change', '.myselect', function(){
       var value = this.value, formPos = $(this).data('formpos');
       //your code
   })
})
```

then while creating

```
elem.data('formpos', config.formPos );
```

---

If you still want to use inlined handler try

```
$(elem).attr('onchange', 'getitemprice(this.value, ' + config.formPos + ');');
```

Comment: This is difficult, no matter what I do, I cannot change the onchang event handler to anything as if it needs to be passed a function and not as string! I executed var stuff = elem.onchange; alert(stuff); and it says onchange is a function event.... No idea how to pass onchange anything like everything else is being passed easily.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
    if($(elem).attr('onchange')){elem.setAttribute("onchange", 'getitemprice(this.value,' + config.formPos + ');');};
```

It allowed me to search only for that one form input that had an onchange event, any onchange event, and i set it using javascript. Couldn't figure out how to do it with JQuery because every time i did

```
    $(elem).attr('onchange',...
```

it would break javascript. I know it isnt elegant, but the only way i could get it to work.
-me-